# Is there a word for a "person who likes bubbles"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a question about bubbles and the people who are particularly fond of them. Would someone please help me find a word for such people? Thank you.

Comment: Obviously, "bubblicious".

Comment: Are you talking about bubble wrap? Or blowing bubbles? Or just bubbly things in general? I vaguely recall hearing or reading a word for someone who likes to pop bubble wrap, but I don’t recall what it was.

Comment: [Thomas Barrett](http://www.liverpoolmuseums.org.uk/picture-of-month/displaypicture.aspx?id=299)?

Comment: Uh, Lawrence Welk? Or how about Don Ho, the singer of that song "Tiny Bubbles"? Don

Comment: Well, ancient Greek words I can find for bubble are pompholuzo (πομφολύζω) and uperbluzo (ὑπερβλύζω), so you could probably add `-phile` to one of those if you feel like making up your own word. Bubble is originally Swedish in origin (bubbla), so you could maybe add `-vän` (or possibly `-älskare`; I don't speak Swedish so I can't say for certain) if you want to go that route. Unfortunately, I don't know of any existing English words that mean what you want.

Comment: Bubblehead?  Bubbleophile?

Comment: @SomethingDark: looking at the [Greek usage](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/searchresults?all_words=pomfo%2Fluc&all_words_expand=yes&la=greek), I would guess more like pompholugophile with a -g- in the stem

Comment: It's 'bubliophile'.

Answer (score 2):

The fear of bubbles is "[ebulliophobia](http://phobia.wikia.com/wiki/Ebulliophobia)," ultimately derived from the Latin *bullare*, to bubble or boil.  So I suppose that term for the opposite condition is "ebulliophilia," making the people thus affected ebulliophiliacs.

Comment: And here I was so hoping for a more ebullient version of this answer.

Comment: @tchrist If only I weren't too old to use emoticons and emojis.  I understand that there are some of those to counteract my depressive personality.

Comment: Strange, I was considering about coining the word effervephile or something without the issue of pronunciation (although ebullient had crossed my mind).

Comment: alas ... is that a neologism?

Comment: @lbf It is your garden variety latin+greek coinage

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you're looking for, but if you'd like to invent such a word, you could use "bulla" which is Latin for bubble, and "amator" which is lover, adorer, admirer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you  like to talk about bubbles and a person or persons who are fond of them, you'll want to have a whole stable of words and phrases.  So here are a few more:

Bubble nut, bubble fan, bubblenik, bubbler, bubble connoisseur, gourmet bubbler, bubble aficionado, bubble expert, bubble enthusiast.

If you are the expert, you could be a bubble mentor, or bubble teacher.  Your mentee could be the bubble initiate, the bubble apprentice.